# How to perform to Template Matching in Emgu CV

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

Sir,

I am new to Emgu CV.I am making a face recognition software.I was able to detect the faces using HaarCascade xml Classifiers.But i m stuck up at the next step regarding how to recognise the face.Anyone please tell me how to use MatchTemplate function...

I found this code on the internet

```
Image<Gray, Byte> templateImage = new Image<Gray, Byte>(bmpSnip);
Image<Gray, float> resultImage = sourceImage.MatchTemplate(templateImage,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TM_TYPE.CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);

float[,,] matches = resultImage.Data;
for (int x = 0; x < matches.GetLength(1); x++)
{
for (int y = 0; y < matches.GetLength(0); y++)
{
double matchScore = matches[y, x, 0];
if (matchScore > 0.75)
{
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(new Point(x,y), new Size(1, 1));
imgSource.Draw(rect, new Bgr(Color.Blue), 1);
}
}
```

I didnt understand this code...First of all this code is not working ....Secondly if anyone know how to do it correctly ... Please post the code.....

Comment: what have you tried?  what have you found on google and what source code do you have for people to look at?   A quick google shows quite a few hits on using template matching as well as questions on SO regarding problems people encountered.

Comment: Some links say that we have to use Eigen faces...some say that we can directly use MatchTemplate function.It will be very helpful if you please post the code about using the MatchTemplate() and recognise faces....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MatchTemplate method is designed preliminary for matching objects with defining features. A face, while to you and I may have defining features to the FFT method employed in MatchTemplate the defining features are simply not large enough for face recognition. Surya is correct as a comparison would be interesting and I would suggest the best approach would to be match areas of the template face image to the recognised face from the camera. So for example you would take the the position of the eyes and apply MatchTemplate to the same location and take an average of matching these features to estimate overall accuracy.

The significant problem you will inherently have however is execution time. With a large database of faces MatchTemplate does not reduce the dataset significantly to allow real time processing.

The Eigen Recogniser is a far safer and efficient method. It will be more reliable than creating your own algorithm and significantly faster. Please see my article here on how to implement it:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/261550/EMGU-Multiple-Face-Recognition-using-PCA-and-Paral

Hope this helps,

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: That's a really great article! I have been having a blast hacking on your sample code for the last few hours—thanks so much for all of the effort that has obviously gone into it.

Comment: Cheers RedFilter very much appreciated. If you want to recognise unknown faces please check the comments bellow the article as I mention there how to do it cheers